# ADOdb_Session How to Set Cookie (Not Only Session)

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working on a project that was developed by someone else and they used ADOdb to manage sessions, basically storing the session key in the DB.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to figure out how to set the session key as a cookie and not just a session so that when you close the browser, and reopen it the cookie still remains as long as the expire time hasn't passed.

Here is the current session.php include file thats being used:

```
include_once("adodb/session/adodb-session2.php");
ADOdb_Session::config(DATABASE_DRIVER, DATABASE_HOSTNAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME, $options=false);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 60*60*48);
session_start();
```

I was checking out the documentation here but can't seem to find anything: http://maltanet.com.br/incs/adodb5/docs/docs-session.htm

Would really appreciate anyone who has experience with this to provide some advice - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) is 0, which means "until the browser is closed."

You can change this with [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) prior to calling `session_start()`.

Comment: Excellent - i'm going to test this now! thank you so much... my php skills are lacking at best.